# Document Sorting Section

Tags: lubuntu, grep, awk, split

I have some sample data below (call it test.txt). I would like to split this big document into 3 documents by searching the first two digits in the 4th column. I'm pretty new with Linux (Lubuntu 14.04) and have looked into 'csplit' and 'awk' but can't seem to get the syntax down for either. (I'm writing BASH scripts)

#### Before:

*test.txt*

```
12-1-2014   Allow   00:00:00 00:00:00
12-1-2014   Allow   00:00:00 00:00:00   
12-2-2014   Allow   01:00:00 01:00:00
12-10-2014  Deny    01:00:00 01:00:00
12-10-2014  Deny    02:00:00 02:00:00
12-11-2014  Deny    02:00:00 02:00:00
```

---

#### After:

*test1.txt*

```
12-1-2014   Allow   00:00:00 00:00:00
12-1-2014   Allow   00:00:00 00:00:00
```

*test2.txt*

```
12-2-2014   Allow   01:00:00 01:00:00
12-10-2014  Deny    01:00:00 01:00:00
```

*test3.txt*

```
12-10-2014  Deny    02:00:00 02:00:00
12-11-2014  Deny    02:00:00 02:00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that maybe :

```
#!/bin/bash

while read LINE ; do
 [[ -n "`echo $LINE | awk '{print " "$NF}' | grep ' 00:'`" ]] && echo "$LINE" | tee -a test1.txt
 [[ -n "`echo $LINE | awk '{print " "$NF}' | grep ' 01:'`" ]] && echo "$LINE" | tee -a test2.txt
 [[ -n "`echo $LINE | awk '{print " "$NF}' | grep ' 02:'`" ]] && echo "$LINE" | tee -a test3.txt
done < test.txt
```

---

Where :

```
while read LINE ; do ; done < FILE
```

is a loop that reads every line of FILE

```
[[ -n "`<command>`" ]] &&
```

means : if `<command>` outputs a non-zero lenght string, then...

```
echo "these are something"| awk {print $NF} | grep 'thing'
```

means : read "these are something", keep only the last column, and see if "thing" is in it.

```
echo "something" | tee -a FILE
```

means : I print "something" in FILE, without overwriting anything and by creating it if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Is it possible to only search for the first two digits in "00:00:00" (HH:MM:SS). I only want to search by hour.

Comment: See the edit, this works for me. It could be better, but I don't know bash very well.

Comment: Your script does work but the problem I didn't mention is that there are two time stamp columns and I need the second one. Sorry.

Comment: Please update your question to be accurate...

Comment: Alright, I changed it. Thank you very much for your help by the way and sorry once again.

Comment: @user289121 : here you go

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`, you could just do

```
awk '{split($3,a,":"); print > "test"a[1]+1".txt";}' test.txt
```

In pure `bash` I'm not sure the best way - although you could do something like

```
while read -r line; do 
  read -r a b c d <<< "$line"
  printf -v outfile "test%d.txt" $(( ${c%%:*} + 1 ))
  printf "%s\n" "$line" >> "$outfile"
done < test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do 
HOUR=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -d':' -f1`;
echo $line >> test-$HOUR.txt;
done < test.txt
```

For each line in file, command `cut` splits line first for `space`, then for `:`. The result is used as suffix for file.

Output are:

```
file-00.txt  file-01.txt  file-02.txt
```

that containing line for hour 00, 01 and so on.